# UIButton above animating CALayer

Tags: ios, uibutton, calayer

I have a `UIButton` with an image which I have positioned just above a `CALayer` which I animate with a flip at certain times. When it flips it can cover up the button. I want to keep the `UIButton` above the layer at all times during this.

I am finding that with bringSubviewToFront it is keeping the UIButton functionality above the `CALayer`, but not the image, so therefore it doesn't look usable and looks covered up.

If anyone has encountered this or has any recommendations I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're calling [buttonContainer bringSubviewToFront:button] or [button bringSubviewToFront:button.imageView].  Have you tried both?